# Cropped image doesn't display correctly inside ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, uiimage, crop

I have rather interesting issue where cropped image is not displaying correctly inside `UIImageView`.

In my app users are able to draw custom shapes and then crop image.
For drawing shapes I used this github library - [ZImageCropper](https://github.com/ZaidPathan/ZImageCropper)

Here's how I crop image:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pickedImage.bounds.size, false, 1)
    pickedImage.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

After that image gets placed inside `UIImageView` and here's what I got:

[image: Cropped Image]

But when I place Image from assets catalog into same `UIImageView` here's the result:

[image: Image From Assets Folder]

Both these images have same size, I have resized cropped image manually when tried to fix this bug but it remained the same. `UIImageView` content mode is **Aspect Fit**.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would imagine that the cropped image is the size of the original image, but what was previously content is now white space.
Perhaps you can test this by setting a background colour behind the image view.

Comment: @InfinityJames Thanks for suggestion. Originally I have transparent background of my image view and Images remain the same, however for this question I have set it intentionally to white, so that you could see image view frame.

Comment: As aforementioned I believe the cropped image is probably not resized such that only the cropped portion is considered a part of the image. You need to resize the rect to only include the remaining portion of the image.